# uitablviewcell height change after presentViewController & dismiss in IOS8

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

I am using self-sizing uitableviewcell in IOS8 (doesn't implement tableviewcell's heightForRowAtIndex, and let autolayout system to decide the height of each cell for tableView) . And self-sizing is working perfect at the view controller first load like this :every image cell got the right height. 
[image]

but if I present a new view controller at this time. And then dismiss the new controller ,I found the height is not correct now like this 
[image]
what's problem here?

Comment: Check your storyboard. Check the cell height set for table view and for prototype cell. Both should be same.

Comment: do I have to do this? because my cell 's height is variable

Comment: Did you set any height in storyboard ? By default it is 44 (think so)

Comment: I think you can try to set `estimatedRowHeight` in `viewWillDisappear` method.

Comment: I did not set any height ,because i think i don't have to set any height for the cell in tableview . the self-sizing system will layout correct for me ( and it was indeed doing right ,after the presentation another controller), am I wrong?

Comment: @gabbler yeah ~ it works ~thanks a lot ~~ can you tell me why i have to set this estimatedRowHeight in viewWillDisappear?

Comment: I know this from experience, I don't know the specific reason though. It might be a bug, it might be that the tableview collapse to default height when disappearing, another option I see is in your `UITableViewCell` subclass, do `layoutIfNeeded` in `didMoveToSuperView`, but I didn't verify that.